# Selecting an item in TreeView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, treeview

Let's say I have this tree:

```
-USA
    -NYC
       -Brooklyn
    -NJ
-France
    -Paris
```

I have a text box (or label or whatever) that writes the path.
I open the tree stage by stage.

**For example:**
If I click USA then NJ it will have: USA/NJ
Or if I click USA then NYC then Brooklyn it will have: USA/NYC/Brooklyn

I want to add text to the path only if it is a child. Meaning, if I click USA and then France, I don't want to have USA/France.

**Is there a way to know if I'm clicking a child?**

BTW, I'm using the `MouseDoubleClick` event.

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: how is the tree getting built , please post your items source.
what i'm getting at is do you have an id and parentId in your nodes ?

Answer (score 0):

Try and get the parent of the element, replacing `TreeViewitem` with whatever control you are using:

```
private void Item_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as TreeViewItem).Parent is TreeViewItem)
    {
       // This is a child
    }
    else
    {
       // This is a root element
    }
}
```